# UITableViewCell Auto-Layout Constraint Problems

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am getting the `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` error in the debugger. I understand that this type of question has been asked on SO many times and I know about how to track the constraints to see what the problem is - but this problem makes no sense to me. I am using the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` feature to auto-resize my cells. Below are my constraints. To simplify the image, every object on the image has a specified height except for the postTextView, which has flexible height so that it can expand with different amounts of text. I want everything else to have a specific height.

Once the constraints are broken, as it states it will try in the console, the layout on-screen is correct and everything behaves as I would expect.

[image]

Here is the error that I get when running the app:

```
2017-08-02 23:29:29.932838-0400 StudyHub[35782:3472431] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048e9c0 UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110.height == 55   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048b680 UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0'.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048ee70 UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60.height == 308   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f550 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f640 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f780 V:[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f8c0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f910 V:[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fb90 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fc30 V:[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000499460 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650.height == 50   (active)>"
)

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048ee70 UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60.height == 308   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-08-02 23:29:29.962013-0400 StudyHub[35782:3472431] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048e9c0 UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110.height == 55   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048b680 UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0'.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f550 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f640 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f780 V:[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f8c0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f910 V:[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fb90 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fc30 V:[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004990f0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60.top == UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5d9c0.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000498fb0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5e110]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000499190 'UISV-fill-equally' UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5e110.height == UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5d9c0.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004991e0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5d9c0]-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5e110]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000499460 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650.height == 50   (active)>"
)

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000004991e0 'UISV-spacing' V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5d9c0]-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5e110]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-08-02 23:29:29.963167-0400 StudyHub[35782:3472431] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048e9c0 UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110.height == 55   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048b680 UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0'.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f550 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f640 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f780 V:[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f8c0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f910 V:[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fb90 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fc30 V:[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000499460 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650.height == 50   (active)>"
)

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048e9c0 UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110.height == 55   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-08-02 23:29:29.963961-0400 StudyHub[35782:3472431] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048b680 UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0'.height == 25   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f550 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f640 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f780 V:[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f8c0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f910 V:[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fb90 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fc30 V:[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000499460 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650.height == 50   (active)>"
)

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048b680 UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0'.height == 25   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2017-08-02 23:29:29.964742-0400 StudyHub[35782:3472431] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f550 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f640 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f780 V:[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']-(8)-[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f8c0 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe16cd5cf60]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f910 V:[UIButton:0x7fe16cd5a1d0'0']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fb90 V:|-(8)-[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048fc30 V:[UIView:0x7fe16cd543b0]-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000499460 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe16cd53650.height == 50   (active)>"
)

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60400048f640 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe16cd55110]-(8)-[UITextView:0x7fe16d8ff000'This is a test of the pos...']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: It's pretty complex, but here's a guess. If the stack view's height isn't constrained it can change in size, but the center must be 38 from the bottom. This means the distance to the bottom varies. However, the distance to the bottom is also constrained by the gap to the buttons below, and their gaps to the bottom. These constraints appear to be fixed. Maybe try removing that center constraint and see what happens.

Comment: I agree.  For auto row sizing to work you need a continuous chain of vertical constraints from top to bottom; you have two due to bottom constraint on the button and the bottom constraint on the stack view.  This is causing a conflict

Comment: I saw a small problem with the graphic I provided and updated it. The vertical constraint is just on the bottom center button and not on the stack view. I have continuous vertical constraints from top to bottom except the center text view has no set vertical height so that it is elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you also need to set the width constraint on your imageView. And also you can try debugging your autolayout constraint by clicking on debug view hierarchy below. [image]

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4** I am creating a demo project:- As per you UIViewController.

> UIViewController Demo:
>   [image]
>   [image]

Please Check the constraints I hope it will work:-